# Script getting failed due to bootstrap ssions

Tags: loadrunner

I downloaded trial version of HP `Loadrunner 12`. I recorded a simple script for login in a web application. But when I replay it, the replay fails and I get the following error. Running Vuser... Starting ...

```
Action.c(74): Error -26621: HTTP Status-Code=410 (Gone) for "http://ericsson.mwfmagic.com/vizql/w/SWS/v/SwapSectorDashboard/bootstrapSession/sessions/1D4FFE382B394A2DB09EEABBB9A47717-0:0"     [MsgId: MERR-26621]
Action.c(74): t=13709ms: Closing connection [0] to ericsson.mwfmagic.com after receiving status code 410    [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(74): t=13709ms: Closed connection [0] to ericsson.mwfmagic.com:80 after completing 14 requests     [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(74): t=13709ms: Request done "http://ericsson.mwfmagic.com/vizql/w/SWS/v/SwapSectorDashboard/bootstrapSession/sessions/1D4FFE382B394A2DB09EEABBB9A47717-0:0"   [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
Action.c(74): Warning -26200: At least one of the resources specified by EXTRARES has not been downloaded due to the above error(s)     [MsgId: MWAR-26200]
Action.c(74): web_submit_data("1D4FFE382B394A2DB09EEABBB9A47717-0:0") highest severity level was "ERROR", 0 body bytes, 298 header bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26388]
Ending action Action.
Ending iteration 1.
Ending Vuser...
Starting action vuser_end.
Ending action vuser_end.
Vuser Terminated.
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to correlate a session ID.